# How to read LF RFID and write it on the phone

Tags: android, rfid, lf

I have an LF RFID tag. I understand that this kind of tag is unreadable with the NFC technology that any Android phone has nowadays. My question is: if I get an RFID reader, can I read LF RFID tag and write it on my phone and use it from my phone with the NFC technology? Or NFC only works with the HF RFID? And if it works, is it any coding involved? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

LF RFID tags operate typically at 125kHz to 134kHz, whereas NFC (which is based on HF RFID) operates at 13.56Mhz. The NFC reader in a smartphone can not read LF tags.
You may be able to find a LF reader device which you can connect to a phone, e.g. via bluetooth. How to operate that depends on the model of the reader.